# Lucky cereal boxes

Tags: probability

Every weak you buy a box of cereals that costs 5 dollars. The company selling the product announces that with a **1%** chance you can find a 10 dollars coupon in the boxes.

a)On average, how many boxes we have to buy before we find our first coupon, and how many money we will have spend on average until then?

b)Find the minimum amount of **n** weeks that you must keep buying the cereals boxes so that in this time you have a probability to find a coupon at least **50%**.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

probability of finding a 10 dollar coupon = 0.1

Expected Number of Boxes = average number of boxes to buy

E = $p(1+2q+3q^2+4q^3+....)$

S = $(1+2q+3q^2+4q^3+....)$

qS = $q+2q^2+3q^3+....)$

S-qS = $1+q+q^2+q^3+\cdots$

S(1-q) = $\frac{1}{(1-q)}$

S = $\frac{1}{(1-q)^2}$

E =$\frac{p}{(1-q)^2}$

E = $\frac{1}{p}$

E = $\frac{1}{.1} = 10$

Amount of money that you need to spend = $5*10 = $50

2nd Part

Probability that you will find it in the nth box = $p(1+q+q^2+q^3+....+ q^{n-1})$

P  = $1-q^{n}$

n = $\frac{log(1-P)}{log(q)}$

n = 6.57

$n  \approx 7$

Comment: Why a downvote?